# Gradle does not display all plugins in dependency tree

Tags: gradle, dependency-graph, dependency-tree, sonar-plugin

**Use Case**

I am trying to generate a dependency tree containing all plugins and dependencies for all configurations, but [org.sonarqube](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube) is not included in the tree. I am working with a basic, single-module project and am using Gradle v7.5.1.

**Examples**

Running the following command outputs **most** (but not all) dependencies and plugins.

`gradlew dependencies > dependency-tree.txt`

*Specify SonarQube plugin within `build.gradle`*

```
plugins {
  id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.2.0'
}
```

*Specify SonarQube plugin within `settings.gradle`*

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.2.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube" // set in build.gradle, not in settings.gradle
```

**Results**

Neither approach includes the `org.sonarqube` plugin in the dependency graph. Is there a way to get this plugin to show up in the generated dependency tree? If yes, what changes need to be made?

Comment: the `dependencies` only works for the main dependencies of the project and you can see if there are any configurations for the plugin. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#example_rendering_the_dependency_report_for_a_custom_configuration

Comment: @PrasadU It doesn't appear any configurations are associated with this plugin. Also went back to the [SonarScanner for Gradle documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-gradle/) and nothing really stood out to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dependencies` task provides the projet dependencies in each configuration, this does not include the projet script classpath (plugins).

You have another similar task available, `buildEnvironment` (see [BuildEnvironmentReportTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.BuildEnvironmentReportTask.html)) which will list the project build script dependencies.
you could combine both tasks outputs if you need a aggredated report of all project/plugin dependencies

```
> Task :buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'demo'
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
\--- org.sonarqube:org.sonarqube.gradle.plugin:3.2.0
     \--- org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.2.0
          \--- org.sonarsource.scanner.api:sonar-scanner-api:2.16.1.361

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 452ms
```